# How I can create a RecyclerView with fixed size image that wrap contents and image is crop centered

Tags: android, image, android-recyclerview, android-wrap-content

this is my desired goal:
[image]
I want to show my Grid Items in 3 rows with recyclerview. I also have fixed image size in dp 120dpx120dp. but I want to my grid Items fill all the vertical space so that there is no blank space in recyclerView and. so I used this layout for Items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:gravity="center">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/view_item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:elevation="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/image_container"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

            <ir.per.ttf.PersianTextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textSize="16sp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout
```

>

but what I see is like this and the image is not cropped center!

[image]

but by reducing image size to 100dpx100dp my RecyclerView do not fill with Items:

[image]

and I can not achieve to my desired view.

this is how I use my Adapter:

```
 GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(context, 3,
                LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        gridLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        holder.horizonrtalItemRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
        RecyclerChambersAdapter recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerChambersAdapter(context, items.get(position),3); //pass context, Items and showing count
        holder.horizonrtalItemRecyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
```

and this is onBind view holder:

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        RecyclerChambersItemViewHolder holder = (RecyclerChambersItemViewHolder) viewHolder;
        try {

            holder.setmyClass(myClasses.get(position));
            holder.setTitle(myClasses.get(position).getName());
            holder.setId(myClasses.get(position).getId());
            holder.setItemImageSrc(myClasses.get(position).getPhoto().getUrl().toString());

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            holder.setItemImageSrc("");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: post your `onBindViewHolder` and the output of `adb shell dumpsys activity top`

Comment: @pskink it is updated

Comment: and `dumpsys` output and `RecyclerChambersItemViewHolder` code..

Comment: @pskink how we can start chat? so I can sed them to you there. and please check and review  my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by changing Grid items by set all `width="match_parent"`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:gravity="center">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/view_item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:elevation="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/image_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:transitionName="@string/transition_avatar"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>

            <ir.per.ttf.PersianTextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:transitionName="@string/transition_title"
                app:customTypeface="@string/primary_font"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

now I achieve my view and items fill all recyclerview space and all images cropped center.